# Sum data.table and get values before each sum

Tags: r

I'm posting this question because I don't how to phrase it in Google :/

I have a data.table of integers

```
421 399 350
```

and I just want to add them but replace each position with the sum at that point.

```
So pos1 would be 421, pos2=421+399, pos3=421+399+350, etc...
```

my final output should look like this:

```
421 820 1170
```

Can you tell me besides answering the question how I can phrase this in english?

Comment: if you meant indeed data.table it would be good to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What you have shown here are vectors, not data.tables.

Comment: Cumulative Sum is the terminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cumsum()`. It does the cumulative sum.